# Send something to the client when the server has finish a function with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, promise, client-server

I'm trying to send a boolean to the client to know when the async call of the server is finished. To do that I made a Promise with some others function like this:

```
'container.stop': function(id) {
        return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
          var ctn = docker.getContainer(id);
          ctn.stop(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                  resolve(false);
              } else {
                  console.log(data);
                  resolve(true);
              }
          }));
        }));
    },
```

*so this is the example of a Promise that works, the client receive when it's finished*

BUT I use now a function that is a bit different and I can't find how to return something to the client:

```
    'machine.stop': function(name) {
            new Machine(name).stop(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err) {
                console.log("Server (stop):" + name)
                if (!err) {
                    checkAlerte(name);
                    InfosMachines.upsert({
                        nameMachine: name,
                    }, {
                        nameMachine: name,
                        stateMachine: 'stopped'
                    });
                    upsertCollectionMachines();
                    //inspect the machine we have created to get her name + data + id
                    new Machine(name).inspect(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result) {
                        if (!err) {
                            // get all datasources
                            var myDatasource;
                            var theIDToDelete;
                            return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
                                // take the ds with the same name as the host
                                HTTP.call("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api/datasources/name/' + ("datasource_" + result.name), {
                                        headers: {
                                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                            'Authorization': APIKEY,
                                        },
                                    },
                                    function(error, result) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            myDatasource = result.data;
                                            resolve(myDatasource);
                                        } else {
                                            console.error(error);
                                        }
                                    });
                            })).then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(myDatasource) {
                                // delete the ds with the id
                                deleteDataSource(myDatasource.id);
                                resolve(true);
                            }));
                        }
                    }));

                } else {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }));
        },
```

*here the client receive nothing but the code of the server works (the machine is stopped and the deleteDatasource is called*

So as you can see I want to return something when the `deleteDatasource` function has been called.

Someone could help me ?
And is it right the way I did my Promise to wait on "myDataSource" to do the `then(` ?

[EDIT] Should I do something like this to return something when the last part is done:

```
then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(myDatasource /*cest la valeur de myDatasource*/) {
                          console.log("4TH step");
                            // delete the ds with the id
                            deleteDataSource(myDatasource.id);
                            return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
                              resolve(true);
                            }));
                        }));
```

Comment: well ... `machine.stop` function doesn't return anything ... what do you need to return?

Comment: @JaromandaX just a boolean to know if it has done all the work that why I did `return new Promise` as in the first example who works

Comment: also, `return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve)` - if that results in an error, the Promise is forever pending - probably a bad coding decision on your part

Comment: @JaromandaX but it doesn't return anything so I don't understand how to return something in this case

Comment: `machine.stop` is still not returning anything - you could put an infinite number of returns in the "inner callback functions" and yet, it will make no difference to what `machine.stop` returns

Comment: @JaromandaX I Founded !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @JaromandaX and @aedm I founded that I should put an other Promise who contains all the code like this:

```
'machine.stop': function(name) {
      return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
        new Machine(name).stop(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, data) {
            console.log("Server (stop):" + name)
            console.log("1ST STEP");
            if (!err) {
                checkAlerte(name);
                InfosMachines.upsert({
                    nameMachine: name,
                }, {
                    nameMachine: name,
                    stateMachine: 'stopped'
                });
                upsertCollectionMachines();
                //inspect the machine we have created to get her name + data + id
                new Machine(name).inspect(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result) {
                  console.log("2ND STEP");
                    if (!err) {
                        // get all datasources
                        var myDatasource;
                        var theIDToDelete;
                         new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
                          console.log("3RD step");
                            // take the ds with the same name as the host
                            HTTP.call("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api/datasources/name/' + ("datasource_" + result.name), {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': APIKEY,
                                    },
                                },
                                function(error, result) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        myDatasource = result.data;
                                        //dit a then que myDataSource est fait
                                        resolve(myDatasource);
                                    } else {
                                        console.error(error);
                                    }
                                });
                        })).then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(myDatasource /*cest la valeur de myDatasource*/) {
                          console.log("4TH step");
                            // delete the ds with the id
                            deleteDataSource(myDatasource.id);
                        }));

                        resolve(true);
                    }
                }));

            } else {
                console.error(err)
            }
        }));
      }));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Meteor method returns a Promise, it's resolved before returning to the client.

Your `container.stop` methods returns a promise, that's why the result you pass to `resolve` is returned to the client. `machine.stop` doesn't have a return value, therefor the Meteor server doesn't wait for the result before answering the Meteor.call.

Comment: Ok I understand what you means, but I can't see how to return something with `machine.stop`

Comment: Only return that makes sense is a promise

Comment: but I try to return the promise @JaromandaX, look I make `return new Promise`  but nothing happens.. and I need to return at the end of the `.then(...)`

Comment: No. You need machine.stop to return a promise. A return in a callback that's in a callback isn't returning anything from the outer function